# Displaying data streamed from an InputStream/InputReader while preserving white spaces

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, whitespace, apache-commons

When capturing the body of the HTTP request within a servlet, I'm seeing different behaviors based on which method I'm using.

**Method 1: (Java 8 streaming)**

```
String body = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
log.info("Received Request {}",body);
```

Produces the log all squished into a single line and thus difficult to read:

```
[java] 02-12-2019 22:14:43 [qtp2056234595-330] INFO  domain.lola.user.utils.actionsongoogle.AoGBotService [handlePOST:98]    - Received AoG Request {  "responseId": "a3da42ef-5728-4d85-bb69-0643f5785804",  "queryResult": {    "queryText": "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME",    "parameters": {      "any": ""    },    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,    "fulfillmentMessages": [{      "text": {        "text": [""]      }    }],    "outputContexts": [{      "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHGy_13Y1OZAVltA6Hj5qTsReoZ8MQrajc0NjBmzNd2Q8Hl7TxIs8x4CFKDlAAqhLGCO82hcwulZt9ZxXw/contexts/google_assistant_welcome",      "parameters": {        "any.original": "",        "any": ""      }    }, {      "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHGy_13Y1OZAVltA6Hj5qTsReoZ8MQrajc0NjBmzNd2Q8Hl7TxIs8x4CFKDlAAqhLGCO82hcwulZt9ZxXw/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output",      "parameters": {        "any.original": "",        "any": ""      }    }, {      "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHGy_13Y1OZAVltA6Hj5qTsReoZ8MQrajc0NjBmzNd2Q8Hl7TxIs8x4CFKDlAAqhLGCO82hcwulZt9ZxXw/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output",      "parameters": {        "any.original": "",        "any": ""      }    }, {      "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHGy_13Y1OZAVltA6Hj5qTsReoZ8MQrajc0NjBmzNd2Q8Hl7TxIs8x4CFKDlAAqhLGCO82hcwulZt9ZxXw/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_keyboard",      "parameters": {        "any.original": "",        "any": ""      }    }, {      "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHGy_13Y1OZAVltA6Hj5qTsReoZ8MQrajc0NjBmzNd2Q8Hl7TxIs8x4CFKDlAAqhLGCO82hcwulZt9ZxXw/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser",      "parameters": {        "any.original": "",        "any": ""      }    }, {      "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHGy_13Y1OZAVltA6Hj5qTsReoZ8MQrajc0NjBmzNd2Q8Hl7TxIs8x4CFKDlAAqhLGCO82hcwulZt9ZxXw/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio",      "parameters": {        "any.original": "",        "any": ""      }    }],    "intent": {      "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/intents/f645f492-f6dc-4e7e-8da6-45711c654ad0",      "displayName": "RawText"    },    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1.0,    "languageCode": "en-us"  },  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {    "source": "google",    "version": "2",    "payload": {      "isInSandbox": true,      "surface": {        "capabilities": [{          "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"        }, {          "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"        }, {          "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"        }, {          "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"        }]      },      "requestType": "SIMULATOR",      "inputs": [{        "rawInputs": [{          "query": "Talk to speech bank",          "inputType": "KEYBOARD"        }],        "intent": "actions.intent.MAIN"      }],      "user": {        "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}",        "lastSeen": "2019-02-12T22:01:13Z",        "locale": "en-US",        "userId": "ABwppHFQHUBr0RrWA_OuL-kK2sxTPUvQtL3D-x2Ydr-7uxLt9zzEFzJrGB-X96d9XY8k9XTJj-RUg9WpzGB9jg"      },      "conversation": {        "conversationId": "ABwppHGy_13Y1OZAVltA6Hj5qTsReoZ8MQrajc0NjBmzNd2Q8Hl7TxIs8x4CFKDlAAqhLGCO82hcwulZt9ZxXw",        "type": "NEW"      }    }  },  "session": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHGy_13Y1OZAVltA6Hj5qTsReoZ8MQrajc0NjBmzNd2Q8Hl7TxIs8x4CFKDlAAqhLGCO82hcwulZt9ZxXw"}
```

**Method 2: (Apache Commons IOUtils)**

```
String rawRequest = IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.toByteArray(request.getInputStream()),UTF_8);
log.info("Received request: {}", rawRequest);
```

produces a pretty printed and thus nicely readable output:

```
 domain.lola.user.utils.actionsongoogle.AoGBotService [handlePOST:101]    - Received request: {
     [java]   "responseId": "f89b8b29-7e4d-4eb6-bb15-f693d8735626",
     [java]     at domain.lola.user.utils.KaiBotService.handle(KaiBotService.java:365)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
     [java]   "queryResult": {
     [java]     "queryText": "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME",
     [java]     "parameters": {
     [java]       "any": ""
     [java]     },
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
     [java]     "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
     [java]     "fulfillmentMessages": [{
     [java]       "text": {
     [java]         "text": [""]
     [java]       }
     [java]     }],
     [java]     "outputContexts": [{
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:369)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)
     [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHFnxMijkuLestJ-UC840GbwybjcxwZ7csve5h2Ee2qiqEUpDqY1c2FyqHancGHTdWEpuXtqL-zyafrTBA/contexts/google_assistant_welcome",
     [java]       "parameters": {
     [java]         "any.original": "",
     [java]         "any": ""
     [java]       }
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1005)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
     [java]     }, {
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
     [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHFnxMijkuLestJ-UC840GbwybjcxwZ7csve5h2Ee2qiqEUpDqY1c2FyqHancGHTdWEpuXtqL-zyafrTBA/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output",
     [java]       "parameters": {
     [java]         "any.original": "",
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
     [java]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
     [java]         "any": ""
     [java]       }
     [java]     }, {
     [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHFnxMijkuLestJ-UC840GbwybjcxwZ7csve5h2Ee2qiqEUpDqY1c2FyqHancGHTdWEpuXtqL-zyafrTBA/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output",
     [java]       "parameters": {
     [java]         "any.original": "",
     [java]         "any": ""
     [java]       }
     [java]     }, {
     [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHFnxMijkuLestJ-UC840GbwybjcxwZ7csve5h2Ee2qiqEUpDqY1c2FyqHancGHTdWEpuXtqL-zyafrTBA/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_keyboard",
     [java]       "parameters": {
     [java]         "any.original": "",
     [java]         "any": ""
     [java]       }
     [java]     }, {
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Intent handler not found - RawText
     [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHFnxMijkuLestJ-UC840GbwybjcxwZ7csve5h2Ee2qiqEUpDqY1c2FyqHancGHTdWEpuXtqL-zyafrTBA/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser",
     [java]     at com.google.actions.api.DefaultApp.handleError(DefaultApp.kt:103)
     [java]       "parameters": {
     [java]         "any.original": "",
     [java]         "any": ""
     [java]       }
     [java]     }, {
     [java]     at com.google.actions.api.DefaultApp.handleError(DefaultApp.kt:98)
     [java]     at com.google.actions.api.DefaultApp.handleRequest(DefaultApp.kt:62)
     [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHFnxMijkuLestJ-UC840GbwybjcxwZ7csve5h2Ee2qiqEUpDqY1c2FyqHancGHTdWEpuXtqL-zyafrTBA/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio",
     [java]       "parameters": {
     [java]         "any.original": "",
     [java]         "any": ""
     [java]       }
     [java]     }],
     [java]     "intent": {
     [java]     ... 17 more
     [java]       "name": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/intents/f645f492-f6dc-4e7e-8da6-45711c654ad0",
     [java]       "displayName": "RawText"
     [java]     },
     [java]     "intentDetectionConfidence": 1.0,
     [java]     "languageCode": "en-us"
     [java]   },
     [java]   "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
     [java]     "source": "google",
     [java]     "version": "2",
     [java]     "payload": {
     [java]       "isInSandbox": true,
     [java]       "surface": {
     [java]         "capabilities": [{
     [java]           "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
     [java]         }, {
     [java]           "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
     [java]         }, {
     [java]           "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
     [java]         }, {
     [java]           "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
     [java]         }]
     [java]       },
     [java]       "requestType": "SIMULATOR",
     [java]       "inputs": [{
     [java]         "rawInputs": [{
     [java]           "query": "Talk to speech bank",
     [java]           "inputType": "KEYBOARD"
     [java]         }],
     [java]         "intent": "actions.intent.MAIN"
     [java]       }],
     [java]       "user": {
     [java]         "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}",
     [java]         "lastSeen": "2019-02-12T21:39:58Z",
     [java]         "locale": "en-US",
     [java]         "userId": "ABwppHFQHUBr0RrWA_OuL-kK2sxTPUvQtL3D-x2Ydr-7uxLt9zzEFzJrGB-X96d9XY8k9XTJj-RUg9WpzGB9jg"
     [java]       },
     [java]       "conversation": {
     [java]         "conversationId": "ABwppHFnxMijkuLestJ-UC840GbwybjcxwZ7csve5h2Ee2qiqEUpDqY1c2FyqHancGHTdWEpuXtqL-zyafrTBA",
     [java]         "type": "NEW"
     [java]       }
     [java]     }
     [java]   },
     [java]   "session": "projects/speechbank-e8a15/agent/sessions/ABwppHFnxMijkuLestJ-UC840GbwybjcxwZ7csve5h2Ee2qiqEUpDqY1c2FyqHancGHTdWEpuXtqL-zyafrTBA"
     [java] }
```

Is there a readable Java 8 stream-based logging output alternative to method 2 (via IOUtils)?

Comment: I think all you're looking for is printing every line from `request.getReader().lines()` in a new line?

Comment: @nullpointer I'm not following

Comment: So I am assuming that `request.getReader().lines()` gives you a `List<String>` (lines), you just need to separate them with `/n` to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code suggested by @GBlodgett didn't compile.

The following expression worked for me:

```
 String rawRequest = request.getReader()
                    .lines()
                    .map(e -> e.concat(System.lineSeparator()))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
 log.info("Received AoG Request {}",rawRequest);
```

or, more efficient, based on a suggestion from @Holger:

```
 String rawRequest = request.getReader()
                .lines()
                //.map(e -> e.concat(System.lineSeparator()))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
 log.info("Received AoG Request {}",rawRequest);
```

I'll leave the measurements of the efficiency gain between those two choices to the reader.

Both of those choices don't need any external dependencies, and are preferred to the **`IOUtils`** option in my case.

Comment: Or just use `.collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()))`, but generally, it’s a waste of resources to split the contents into lines, just to join them afterwards.  The IOUtils solution pointed into a better direction (when a complete string is what you need). But `IOUtils.toString(…, UTF_8)` is obsolete, as you can just use `new String(…, UTF_8)`. Starting with Java 9, you also don’t need `IOUtils.toByteArray` anymore; you can use `new String(request.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), UTF_8)`.

Comment: @Holger Given we are not using Java 9, would you say a preferred way would be via mapping to lineSeparator or via joining on it, as you suggested stating that it's also wasteful?  First is more explicit, I guess, but similarly wasteful.  Or not?

Comment: `.map(e -> e.concat(System.lineSeparator()))` creates intermediate strings, which requires copying the character contents of the incoming strings. Plus the joining. So, using `collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()))` will be more efficient in most cases. Unlike the mapping approach, it will not append a line break after the last line, but for the purpose of logging, you don’t need a final line terminator anyway. But why not `IOUtils.toString(request.getReader())`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to have every line from the request on its separate line. To do this you can append a newline to every line:

```
String body = request.getReader()
                     .lines()
                     .map(e -> e + System.lineSeparator()) 
                     //Or e.concat(...)  
                     .collect(Collectors.joining());
log.info("Received Request {}",body);
```

Comment: Kinda what I was assuming as well. Not sure if OP is really after this though.

Comment: This complains that it `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)`